# I get an error when using the dynamic byte array in delphide

Tags: delphi

I'm doing a project with delphi. The project has c # codes. I'm using the byte array in the project. But I get an error. C # codes:

```
public class DataTransmitEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public DataTransmitEventArgs(byte[] transmittedBytes)
        {
            fTransmittedBytes = transmittedBytes;
        }
        byte[] fTransmittedBytes;
        public byte[] TransmittedBytes
        {
            get { return fTransmittedBytes; }
        }
    }
```

and my Delphi codes:

```
DataTransmitEventArgs = class

 public
 fTransmittedBytes: array of byte;
 constructor  Create(transmittedBytes: array of byte);overload;
 property TransmittedBytes[index: byte]:Byte read fTransmittedBytes;
 end;

  constructor DataTransmitEventArgs.Create(transmittedBytes: array of byte);
     begin
             fTransmittedBytes := transmittedBytes;
     end;
```

how do i do these c # codes with delphi

Comment: Read this: http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-openarr.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to specify what error message you receive and on what line (always do that!), but almost certainly it was E2008: Incompatible types at the `property` line.

According to the documentation, which should always be your first source for information, an [array property](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Properties_(Delphi)#Array_Properties) cannot have fields (like `fTransmittedBytes`) as its access specifiers (read or write). Instead, they must be methods:

> For array properties, access specifiers must list methods rather than fields. The method in a read specifier must be a function that takes the number and type of parameters listed in the property's index parameter list, in the same order, and whose result type is identical to the property's type. The method in a write specifier must be a procedure that takes the number and type of parameters listed in the property's index parameter list, in the same order, plus an additional value or const parameter of the same type as the property.

Let's do an example:

```pascal
type
  TTest = class
  private
    FData: array of Byte;
  public
    property Data[Index: Integer]: Byte read FData write FData;
  end;
```

violates this requirement and emits E2008 at the `read` (and `write` if you fix the `read`).

Instead, you must do

```pascal
type
  TTest = class
  private
    FData: array of Byte;
    function GetData(Index: Integer): Byte;
    procedure SetData(Index: Integer; const Value: Byte);
  public
    property Data[Index: Integer]: Byte read GetData write SetData;
  end;

{ TTest }

function TTest.GetData(Index: Integer): Byte;
begin
  Result := FData[Index];
end;

procedure TTest.SetData(Index: Integer; const Value: Byte);
begin
  FData[Index] := Value;
end;
```

If you want additional safety, do (`uses Math`)

```pascal
function TTest.GetData(Index: Integer): Byte;
begin
  if InRange(Index, Low(FData), High(FData)) then
    Result := FData[Index]
  else
    raise Exception.CreateFmt('Index out of bounds: %d', [Index]);
end;

procedure TTest.SetData(Index: Integer; const Value: Byte);
begin
  if InRange(Index, Low(FData), High(FData)) then
    FData[Index] := Value
  else
    raise Exception.CreateFmt('Index out of bounds: %d', [Index]);
end;
```

Alternatively, it is quite possible to skip the property and have the field be public:

```pascal
type
  TTest = class
  public
    Data: array of Byte;
  end;
```

Finally, it is possible to have the field private but a public property of a [dynamic array](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Dynamic_Arrays) type:

```pascal
type
  TTest = class
  private
    FData: TArray<Byte>;
  public
    property Data: TArray<Byte> read FData write FData;
  end;
```

If you are on a pre-generics version of Delphi, `TArray<Byte>` is obviously not available,  so you then have to define your own type: `type ByteArray = array of Byte`.

---

In addition, you have

```
constructor  Create(transmittedBytes: array of byte);overload;
```

which should be

```
constructor Create(const ATransmittedBytes: array of Byte); overload;
```

Always use `const` on [open array parameters](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Open_Array_Parameters):

> When you pass an array as an open array value parameter, the compiler creates a local copy of the array within the routine's stack frame. Be careful not to overflow the stack by passing large arrays.

---

Finally, your

```
fTransmittedBytes := transmittedBytes;
```

will not compile, either, because you cannot simply assign an [open array](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Open_Array_Parameters) to a [dynamic array](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Dynamic_Arrays).

Instead, you can change the parameter to a dynamic array type:

```
constructor Create(const ATransmittedBytes: TArray<Byte>); overload;
```

You might then also want to `Copy` the array:

```
FTransmittedBytes := Copy(ATransmittedBytes);
```

Alternatively, you can use `SetLength` and a simple `for` loop to copy the array:

```
SetLength(FTransmittedBytes, Length(ATransmittedBytes));
for i := 0 to High(ATransmittedBytes) do
  FTransmittedBytes[i] := ATransmittedBytes[i];
```

The lower bound of an open array is always `0`.

Comment: Even though the lower bound of open arrays is always 0, I'd still recommend using Low(ATransmittedBytes) - just to get in the habit of using Low/High on array index limits.